# Break nested loop based on different strings in 1 column

Tags: python, nested-loops

```
name  seta  setb    setc
0    aaa  1111  1111  1111.0
1    aaa  1112  1121  1211.0
2    aaa  1113  1131  1311.0
3    aaa  1114  1141  1411.0
4    aaa  1115  1151  1511.0
5    aaa  1116  1161  1611.0
6    aaa  1117  1171  1711.0
7    aaa  1118  1181  1811.0
8    aaa  1119  1191  1911.0
9    aaa  1120  1201  2011.0
10  bbbb  1111  1111  1111.0
11  bbbb  1112  1121  1211.0
12  bbbb  1113  1131  1311.0
13  bbbb  1114  1141  1411.0
14  bbbb  1115  1151  1511.0
15  bbbb  1116  1161     NaN
16  bbbb  1117  1171     NaN
17  bbbb  1118  1181     NaN
18  bbbb  1119  1191     NaN
19  bbbb  1120  1201     NaN
```

**I would like to seek your help how do I loop from row 0 - 9 break then continue loop from row 10 - 19.**

```
# These are the codes I have
name_col = []
seta_col = []
setb_col = []
setc_col = []

for i in data['name']:
  if i not in name_col:
    name_col.append(i)
for i in data['seta']:
  seta_col.append(i)
for i in data['setb']:
  setb_col.append(i)
for i in data['setc']:
  setc_col.append(i)

df_list = []
for name in name_col:
  for sa in seta_col:
    for sb in setb_col:
      for sc in setc_col:
        if name!=name:
          break
        print(name,sa,sb,sc)
```

I try adding break but it did not help. I tried adding new empty after every new string but it doesn't work.

Comment: why you want to do like this?

Comment: why do you want to break at 9 if you want to continue from 10 again

Comment: what is the point of braking on 9 and continuing on 10? Also, why are you checking if name != name when that will never be the case? Did you perhaps mean to say previous name != name? Also, if your structure is constant you can just use `enumerate` and use the index to know when you should break out of the loop. Which still doesn't make sense really.